# Best approach for storing commonly used database table IDs?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

What is the best approach for storing database table IDs that are used often?

For example you have a table that stores Record statuses, such as active deleted, purged etc.  You want to create a new User record and you need to set the RecordStatusID, where would you get that data?  Do a database call?

I've seen developers create enums that matches the tables int IDs, but I don't think that is the best way.

Comment: Best way for what? Performance? Memory use? Development? Consistency?

Comment: @Oded To be honest I'd like to hear a suggestion for any of those, but probably for me I'd choose performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your application logic depends on those values, and so changing the table means changing your code, I prefer creating enums that mirror the table.

Doing this creates readable code with no need for magic strings that could contain a typo (although you replace them with magic numbers in the enum definition). And the code is efficient without unnecessary queries.

Comment: I too have used this method lots and found it works nicely. The only problem I've ever had is with migrating data to a new database if using identity columns for the id - easy to work around (e.g. set identityinsert on) but can be a gotcha if forgotten.

Comment: +1 yes, my approach, too - plus with T4, you can even generate those enum files directly from the database tables

Comment: @DavidHall, tables like this are usually fairly small and are modified rarely, so I don't see any reason for using identity column for the id.

Comment: You could always use GUIDs as the ID or add a second column which would designate a 'KEY' that is never modified.

Comment: @M3NTA7, using just GUIDs this way wouldn't work, because you can't have enums based on GUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on a large number of factors and trade-offs between those factors. For example, if you have a table with 10 rows that will never change, then you may as well define an emum, or read it once when you start the application and work off a cache. But there are plenty of cases where the data might change (even if infrequently) and caching it once could be a horrible strategy. It's hard to answer a question like this without having that contextual information, and there is no one-size-fits-all solution to a problem like this.

Can you give us some more specific information about the data you're dealing with? That will most likely lead to better answers that won't inadvertently come back to bite you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table in the database that contains the default values and at the application start up, read them and store them in a Dictionary object. Then from within your .NET code you just access the values by name. That way if the values need to be changed, they can be changed in the database without the need to update .NET code.